# Rspec Create multiple posts to check ranking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Afternoon All,

I've just starting learning the testing side of rails and having some trouble with this below.

Let me quickly explain what I'm trying to test. If a user creates 10 approved snippets their rank should == "Author". A snippet is created on a book which I have listed in the factories but my code is all messed up and I'm not sure how I would write this.

Here is the code I've been playing with for the testing:

```
describe "ranking" do

    let!(:book) { Book.create }

    let!(:snippet) { FactoryGirl.create(:snippet1, :book1 => book) }

      context "should be author after 10 approved posts" do

         10.times do

          FactoryGirl.create(:snippet1)

         end

         user.user_rank.should == "Author"

      end

  end
```

Here are my factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :admin2, class: User do

    first_name "admin1"

    last_name "minstrator"

    password "admin1234"

    profile_name "profilename"

    email "admin1@admin.com"

    password_confirmation "admin1234"

    admin true

    end



    factory :user2, class: User do

    first_name "user2"

    last_name "man2"

    password "user1234"

    profile_name "profilename"

    email "user2@user.com"

    password_confirmation "user1234"

    admin false

    end



    factory :book1, class: Book do

    title "Book1"

    approved true

    size 0

    end



    factory :snippet1, class: Snippet do

    content "Snippet1"

    approved true

    end



  end
```

EDIT: Error and related code:

```
app/models/snippet.rb:32:in `size_limit': undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

This relates to a validation in the model shown below:

```
  BOOK_SIZE = { 

    0 => {'per' => 500, 'total' => 15000},

    1 => {'per' => 700 , 'total' => 30000},

    2 => {'per' => 1000, 'total' => 50000}

  }





   def size_limit 

    book_limit = self.book.size.to_i

    word_count = self.content.scan(/\w+/).size.to_i

    current_snippets_size = (self.book.get_word_count || 0) + word_count 

    errors.add(:base, "Content size is too big") unless word_count < BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['per'] && current_snippets_size < BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['total']    

  end
```

Comment: so then what happens?  the tests aren't passing?  are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your snippet1 factory should have user_id or something like that. now you create 10 snippet without association

**edit**: now I read your edit. but hire is almost the same. your snippet1 factory haven't any book so error on this

```
self.book.size.to_i
```

Comment: Ok so am I able to define the book factory in the snippet factory? I thought the join on the let! did that.

Comment: also you can define it the same like you create "let!(:snippet)..." so something like: "FactoryGirl.create(:snippet1, user_id: user.id, book_id: book.id)". I'm not sure how your associations look.
or you can build in factory "association :user"

Answer (score 1):

Your `let(:snippet)` clause uses a `:book1` attribute, but the code is checking the `self.book` – could that be it?

Either way, the snippet.rb excerpt you've listed has two references to `.size` - without knowing your line numbers, it's hard for us to tell which one is throwing the error.

So either the book attribute or the content attribute is returning nil – and so when you call size on that nil attribute you get the error that's happening.

If snippet is only valid with a book reference and a non-nil content, add validations for those conditions. If there are situations where those attributes *could* be nil, make sure that your code makes allowances for that.